# Does the "+ Attack Damage" modifier increase my bow damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing a custom map right now, and I just got a piece of armor that has a modifier of "+25% Attack Damage". Obviously this increases my melee damage, but does it have any effect on bow damage? It stands to reason that it should, but I know bow damage in Minecraft is a little weird, so I'm not sure if it does or not. It's really hard to tell.

Will this modifier increase the amount of damage I can deal with a bow? Or will it only have an effect on sword damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Attack Damage` attribute only affects melee damage, even it is applied directly to the bow rather than onto armor. It does affect left click hitting with a bow, but not shooting.

I tested this by giving myself items with high `+ Attack Damage` attributes, and counting how many attacks it took to kill a mob:

[image]

This piece, for example, was an instakill with a sword on everything, but the normal amount of shots with a bow. (I also tested items with lower `+ Attack Damage` in case some kind of max value was stopping the bow from applying the insanely high extra damage.)